# Android ZXingScanner (QR Scanner) and Torch

Tags: android, camera, zxing, torch

I added ZXing qr scanner to my android project with compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'.

I am displaying the qrcode scanner inside of a fragment.  I can scan and read without any problems.  The issue I am having is trying to turn the flash (torch) on while the camera is scanning.

this code scans perfectly

```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qrscan, container, false);
      mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(getActivity());   
      mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a   
      mScannerView.startCamera();
      return mScannerView;
```

this code turns on the torch perfectly

```
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
        return view;
```

If I try to turn the light on and return mScannerview the scanner works but the light goes off.  I can't seem to get the light and the qr scanner to work together successfully. The light does not work or my code will throw an exception depending on the code I try.  I have tried to use the first bit of code and turn on the torch in the onResume().  But I am not successful.  It is not a permission issue I can turn the light on and off without issues.  I can scan no problem.  But I can not scan with the light on.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying variations on this.

I saw one solution which involved starting a thread that runs every few seconds, checks if the light is off and (if it is off) turns it on. I couldn't get it working properly.

Another possible solution is to try recoding the project to allow external switching of the light on or off on creation of the page.